# How to specify the length of the substring in a SELECT ... LIKE query

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a query that contains this LIKE condition:

`where col like concat(?, '%')`

`?` will be filled with the content of a variable.

What I want is, for example, if `? length < 5` instead of using like, I would like to use an exact match: `where col = 'bla'` then if `? length >= 5` use the `like concat` like the provided example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
where ( (length(?) < 5 and name = ?) or
        (length(?) >= 5 and name like concat(?, '%'))
      )
```

This can be simplified to:

```
where (name = ? or
       (length(?) >= 5 and name like concat(?, '%'))
      )
```

Or even to:

```
where name like concat(?, (case when length(?) < 5 then '' else '%' end))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved, for example, with CASE statement in your query:

```
select * from table_name where name like (
case 
when length(?) < 5 
    then ?
else
    concat(?, '%')
END
);
```